# Livewire turns collection into array

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

In `mount()` function of livewire component I have a collection, whick looks like this:

```php
$this->products = $purchase->getProductsList();
```

`getProductsList()` is a function of Purchase model:

```php
public function getProductsList() : Collection
{
    $products = $this->purchaseSkus->pluck('sku.product')->unique();
    return $products;
}
```

Whenever component's blade is rendered - it works ok

[image]

But in the same blade I have a textarea with `wire:model="description"` and function `updatedDescription()` in component. And after making changes in textarea `$products` turns into array

[image]

How can I prevent it?

P.S.: If I put `$this->products` into `render()` function - it works ok too.

Answer (score 14):

There are two different collections in Laravel, the "default" one `Illuminate\Support\Collection` - and an additional one for Eloquent collections, `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. You should be using the second one - as Livewire will better know how to serialize/unserialize an Eloquent-collection of models with this.

`pluck()` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` - which Livewire will hydrate as an array. Anything that isn't a Model or an Eloquent Collection, will be hydrated as an array (aside from non-iterable objects like strings, intergers, booleans, etc).

To fix this, you can get the data via the Product model, something like this. Since I've not seen the actual relations, or what `$this->purchaseSkus` is, this is somewhat pseudo-code, and you should fix the relation `sku.purchase` to what it actually is. This gets all products where there is a relation to the data in `$this->purchaseSkus`.

```
public function getProductsList() : Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
{
    return Product::whereHas('sku.purchase', function($query) {
            return $query->whereIn('id', $this->purchaseSkus->puck('id'));
        })
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: But in the future normal collections should be supported too, because sometimes you have data that isn't related to any model. Sometimes you just want your data as a collection so you can access it in the view like an object, that was the case for me, but I think I'll have to go with arrays for now ; )

Comment: A normal collection is supported, but if the contents of the collection are objects like models, Livewire cannot possibly know how to rehydrate it. Same goes for any other objects. With a newer version of Livewire, there is now a `boot()` lifecycle method, which means you can perform some logic there to hydrate it yourself. You can also hook into the `hydrate()` method directly

Comment: @Qirel you are right and your comment helped me realize how to work with Collection of DTOs. I can use hydrateFoo() f-n and simply update my collection with the right object class instead of array