# Issue when adding an item to a public Livewire property in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, collections, laravel-livewire

I've encountered an unusual issue while working on a Livewire component in Laravel. In my component, I have a public variable called `$this->temp_items`, which is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. I've implemented a method named `additem` to add items to this collection.

The problem arises when I call this method for the second time. It appears that the first object I added to the collection gets transformed into an array, losing its original type, which should be an object of type `App\Models\Stock`.

Here's the code for my `additem` method for reference:

```php
public function additem() {
    if (!empty($this->product)) {
        // Retrieve data into a single model variable.
        $this->order_items = Stock::where('products.id', '=', $this->product_id)
            ->where('departments.id', '=', $this->department_id)
            ->join('departments', 'stocks.department_id', '=', 'departments.id')
            ->join('products', 'stocks.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->join('supplier_product', 'stocks.product_id', '=', 'supplier_product.product_id')
            ->join('suppliers', 'supplier_product.supplier_id', '=', 'suppliers.id')
            ->join('types', 'products.type_id', '=', 'types.id')
            ->select('stocks.id as stock_id', 'stocks.sku', 'departments.desc_department', 'products.title', 'types.desc_type', 'products.color', 'suppliers.company_name')
            ->first();

        $this->validate(['amount_ordered' => 'required|integer|min:1']);

        $this->order_items->setAttribute('amount_ordered', $this->amount_ordered);

        $this->order->finished = 0;

        // Retrieve the items to save and add another chosen item. Here is the problem. On the second manual trigger, the first item collection was changed to an array, and the second item is of the correct type.
        // This problem is illustrated in the second screenshot below.
        $this->temp_items->add($this->order_items);

        // Here is a block just to check if the addition is correct. The `dd` output is in the next screenshot.
        $i = 0;

        do {
            $this->temp_items->add($this->order_items);
            $i += 1;
        } while ($i < 10);

        dd($this->temp_items); // The output is in the next print #1.
    }
}
```

[image: #1 print showing a iteration in a unique trigger]

[image: #2 the problem showing that my first item was transformed]

I'm using Livewire to build this component, and Laravel as my backend framework.

- I have attempted various methods available for adding an item to the collection, such as `prepend`, `put`, `push`, etc.
- The variable is already instantiated in the `mount` method of the component:

  ```php
  public function mount()
  {
      $this->temp_items = new Collection();
  }
  ```
- I have utilized all the lifecycle methods, including `updating`, `hydrate`, `dehydrate`, etc.
- I have tried declaring the property as a collection type:

  ```php
  public Collection $temp_items;
  ```
- I have also attempted to declare it as an Eloquent collection by assigning the variable the type of the `stock` model.

As you can see [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk0DW.png), the first item is always loaded correctly because it is rendered by accessing the variables as if it were a collection using "->". However, when it transforms the first item into an array, it starts rendering the data with square brackets.
Does anyone know what might be causing this transformation of objects into arrays, and how I can prevent it from happening?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!
If you need further assistance or clarification, please feel free to ask.

Comment: I have never used Livewire, but, out of my mind, I think it may make sense that the issue is that it is transformed to an array, as you will consume that in the frontend with javascript, so it must be an array or a JSON. Still, I am very ignorant about it, so maybe it should be passed as a Collection, but I have no idea :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Livewire turns collection into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466137/livewire-turns-collection-into-array)

Comment: Hi @Qirel. Thanks for spending your time on this. I had been reading this suggestion, and I'll try your thoughts. However, I've already tried the hydrate() hook. Could you suggest another approach in the hydrate method? If I have finished, I'll let you know. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You'll just need to change the collection class to the Eloquent Collection. No need to touch the hydration. Read the first part of my answer in that link.